# any interpretation for $\left[ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} w^{2n} \right]^{-1}$?

Tags: reference-request, theta-functions

One very simple version of the theta function is as a generating function over the perfect squares:

$$ \theta(\tau; z) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} w^{2n} $$

Where $q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and $w = e^{\pi i z}$.  I want to know what is the "meaning" or series-expansion of the reciprocal of the theta function:

$$ \frac{1}{\theta(q,w)} = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (\dots)q^n $$

This is the kind of things I might run through a computer, I still have no idea what the coefficients should mean.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it leads anywhere, but an idea might be to use [Jacobi triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product), write each factor as a [q-Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) and use the formula on the wikipedia for the inverse of such symbols to try and come up with a physical interpretation...